# Does ASME follow the ANSI standard, the ISO standard, or neither (both work)?

Tags: drafting

[image]

I was looking through AMSE Y14-5 and noticed that they tend to use diameter symbols in their drawings, which is indicative of an ISO standard.
[image]
[image]

However, I always thought that ASME Y14-5, being American, would follow ANSI as opposed to ISO. Such as this random person online who mentioned that ASME follows ANSI : https://grabcad.com/questions/what-is-the-difference-between-ansi-and-iso-drafting-standard

Doing a quick search online I've gotten only more confused, and was wondering if someone could explain/help clarify this.

Edit: Even sites like this: https://www.cobanengineering.com/geometricdimensioningandtolerancing/TechnicalDrawingLines.asp

seem to say that diameter symbols, and calling out a radius as R0.250 is ANSI.

I am very lost :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ASME follows the ANSI drafting standard.

Both ANSI and ISO have adopted many of the other standard as an alternative, so many companies have mixed and matched the drafting standards to create their own, oddball standard.

The basic, visual differences between the ANSI drafting standard and ISO drafting standard:

ANSI dimensions are read horizontally. ISO dimensions are parallel to the dimension line.

ANSI dimensions are centered on the dimension line. ISO dimension are placed above the dimension line.

ANSI tends to use abbreviations. ISO uses symbols. (example: RAD, DIAM, 3 PLACES versus R, Ø, 3X)

dimensions have a different syntax.
ANSI: 1.000 DIAM 3 PLACES
ISO: 3X Ø 1

I would suggest you google for them. Many are not free and you need to pay for them. Start by looking for a list of the standards, there are lots of them. https://www.asme.org/codes-standards  https://www.iso.org/standards.html  https://www.ansi.org/   These are the home pages, this should get you started/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you know anywhere I can read up more on the ANSI, or ISO standards? Also, I wonder why the official ASME diagrams would show ISO symbols, and have that "mix" you mentioned.

Comment: If you want to know what the standards say, read the standards. (They are not free, because they are produced by teams of experienced people who have to be paid for doing a soul-destroying task like writing standards, instead of something else that pays well and is more interesting!) If you want to know what "some guys on the internet" *think* they say - well it should be obvious what to do!

Comment: More likely ANSI and ISO follow ASME  as ASME was the first general standard. ISO is a relative newcomer, not to offend any national pride.

Comment: Just a note, I and many others serve or have served on these committees as volunteers, not paid members. Some may draw wages from there employer to do this but not all. Yes we have to pay for the standards we were not involved with drafting.

Comment: I see, I didn't know what ASME was the first! Thanks for that information.